# Error en fechas en laravel 5.5 y SQLServer

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, laravel-5, sql-server-2005

Al insertar cualquier fecha en laravel 5.5 hacia una base de datos SQLserver me da el siguiente error:

```
SQLSTATE[22003]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]
Error de desbordamiento aritmético al convertir expression al tipo de datos datetime.
```

Al parecer se debe a que laravel envía la fecha con formato 'Y-m-d H:i:s.000' (2017-10-24 13:22:35.000)

Hasta ahi todo bien el problema es que antes de ejecutar esa consulta laravel envia las siguientes instrucciones a la base de datos:

```
-- network protocol: TCP/IP
set quoted_identifier on
set arithabort off
set numeric_roundabort off
set ansi_warnings on
set ansi_padding on
set ansi_nulls on
set concat_null_yields_null on
set cursor_close_on_commit off
set implicit_transactions off
set language Español
**set dateformat dmy**
set datefirst 1
set transaction isolation level read committed
```

**set dateformat dmy** significa que debería recibir 'd-m-Y H:i:s.000' pero no se cómo cambiar la configuración para que las instrucciones y las querys sean consistentes.

¿Cómo puedo corregir este error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente solucione el tema mediante poner el formato de fecha no convencional en cada modelo...

```
protected $dateFormat = 'd-m-Y H:i:s';
```

ahora el tema de los pasword_reset lo arregle modificando en el codigo local de laravel lo siguiente:

```
vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\DatabaseTokenRepository.php
protected function getPayload($email, $token)
    {
        return [
            'email' => $email, 'token' => $this->hasher->make($token),
            'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('d-m-Y H:i:s')
        ];
    }
```

Aunque la respuesta mas correcta que se podria llevar a cabo es la de taylor:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/653#issuecomment-15459517

No se si alguien me podria guiar con este proceso para poder llevarlo a cabo...
Formulé esta pregunta en la siguiente pagina:
[Modificar conexion a SQL Server desde Laravel 5.5 para manipular fechas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/112672/modificar-conexion-a-sql-server-desde-laravel-5-5-para-manipular-fechas)

Comment: Que bueno que hayas solucionado tu problema, pero: `No se si alguien me podría guiar con este proceso para poder llevarlo a cabo...` = esa es una pregunta nueva, debes formular una nueva pregunta.

Comment: También recuerda [aceptar tu propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

No pones un ejemplo de tu código, pero puedes formatear la fecha con esta línea de código:

```
echo Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H', '1975-05-21 22')->toDateTimeString();
```

ó

con esta otra línea de código:

```
date("d-m-Y H", strtotime('1975-05-21 22'));
```

Y enviar el formato como lo espera el servidor.

Revisando la documentacion de laravel el modelo tiene un metodo setDateFormat talvez eso te ayude.

https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_setDateFormat

Revisando el código el `dateFormat` se define en `getDateFormat` del archivo:

**src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/SqlServerGrammar.php**

Talvez puedas hacer un extends y usar ese Grammars

Comment: La verdad es que todo el codigo es directo de la función de laravel make:auth el tema esta en la conexión a la base de datos a msqlserver... no puedo manipular los request de password reset o las de registro de usuarios y demas. lo ideal seria que la app no envie la instruccion **set dateformat dmy** al servidor sql asi se manejarian las fechas sin problema en el formato que tiene la base de datos y laravel 'Y-m-d H:i:s.000'