# Modificar conexion a SQL Server desde Laravel 5.5 para manipular fechas

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, laravel-5

Segun lo que indica Taylor aca en este comentario:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/653#issuecomment-15459517

> Probablemente necesite anular el enlace de la base de datos en el IoC e inyectar una implementación de ConnectionFactory personalizada en el administrador de la base de datos.

Quien puede ayudarme para hacer esto?
Un saludo y de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Tradujiste demasiado literal la respuesta, esta haciendo referencia al array "sqlsrv" de configuración de "config/database", pero igualmente no te tienes que preocupar de las fechas para tratarlas ya que se parsearan a un objeto "Carbon" el cual podras tratar igual en cualquier base de datos y se adapta a cualquier cosa que necesites.
Aun así si quieres modificar el formato por defecto de las fechas solo añade esta función con el formato deseado.

> public function getDateFormat() { return 'Y-m-d H:i:s.0000000'; }